# Swift 4 - what's the best practice to determine if an instance is an Array with specific generic type?

Tags: swift, swift4

```swift
let item: [String] = [""]
print(item is [Int]) //false
print(type(of: item) == [Int].self) //false
```

the compiler warning: Cast from '[String]' to unrelated type '[Int]' always fails

The result is as expected. But:

```swift
let item: [String] = []
print(item is [Int]) //true
print(type(of: item) == [Int].self) //false
```

When the array is empty, the "is" result is: true

The question is: what's the best practice to determine if an instance is an Array with specific generic type?

type(of:) ?

"is" ?

"is" keyword seems not as good as type(of:) in this situation.

Comment: That is just a compiler warning, not an error, so what is your question? The warning is obviously correct, your example is not a real example of what you are trying to achieve, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DávidPásztor question updated. Please have a look.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you designing a generic function which should work differently for different element types of arrays? Or do you simply want to check the type of the elements in an array?

Comment: You seem to already know the answer to your question – if you want to check the *exact* type of an instance, then use `type(of:)`. If you also want to include types that the instance can be implicitly converted to, then use `is`. Although the spurious warning in the empty array case is a bug, which [I have filed a report for](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6192).